# Calibration of a stochastic python simulation

Tags: python, optimization, calibration, agent-based-modeling, stochastic

I have an (agent-based) simulation in python. The results are stochastic. I would like to calibrate the simulation be minimizing a sum of square distances. 
What python algorithms are available to minimize a stochastic simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, for example how is "distance" calculated? I can only give general advice. I suggest scipy's [optimization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) module. Depending on whether the sum is a scalar or a vector, you can use a different optimizer.

If you are unfamiliar with the different optimization methods, I suggest looking through [this brief overview](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#gradient-based-methods).

Comment: thanks good info. Are you sure that the optimization module can deal with stochastic results?

Comment: The distance is Sum(w(x - y)^2), where x is a measurment of an outcome of real live and y is an outcome of the abm. For example the highest increase in price observed in the simulation/reality.

Comment: Awesome so  Nelder-Mead (scipy.optimize.fmin()) or Powell (scipy.optimize.fmin_powell()), can deal with noisy results.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure what you mean by stochastic results - statistics uses the likelihood function, which is by definition related to stochastic results. But the optimization packages will just try to maximize a scalar or vector using whatever function you give it. Slightly related, is you might want to keep the stochastic element outside of the optimization. If you constantly drawn random values for each iteration of the optimizer, you will get noisy results.

Comment: I think the OP meant that the function outcome is itself random - it can be slightly perturbed on each call - by quick googling I found http://noisyopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but I am not sure this is the best. @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad what made you think that "scipy.optimize.fmin can deal with noisy results"?